# Tikz picture inline

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there any way of placing a tikzpicture code inline? Here is what I want to actuall achieve:

> A convex function is denoted by "*tikz code for convexity*"

Someone told me this is possible. Also, in tikz-pgf tutorial I have seen many tikz codes inline. For example in the scaling section the author places a rotating ellipse inline (that is next to the text)

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You should take into account, that 'inline' means normally on the same baseline, so this might stretch the line height, since tikz figures are usually larger than `1ex`

Comment: A `tikzpicture` is not really much different from the letter `X`, in that as far as TeX is concerned it is just a box that it is placed on the current baseline.

Comment: Thank you all either for your answers or your comments. I accept the second one but I guess that Rmano's answer will come in handy some time. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Either use `tikzpicture` as an environment or the `\tikz` inline macro.

But the problem with the line stretching is quite obvious!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}
A stupid text followed by \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[fill=red,line width=1pt]  circle(1ex);\end{tikzpicture}

A stupid text followed by \tikz{\draw[fill=red,line width=1pt]  circle(1ex);}

A stupid text followed by another stupid text followed

A stupid text followed by some dots \tikz{%
    \foreach \x /\cola in {1/blue,2/yellow,3/red,4/green,5/orange}  {%
      \shade[ball color=\cola] (\x,0)  circle(0.5ex*\x);
    }%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: isn't just `\tikz ... ;` without the braces? (Seems to work both way, though). +1.

Comment: @Rmano: Yes, you're right. I am not using `\tikz...` very often.

Comment: @Tolaso: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @to myself: use \protect before \tikz in captions

Answer (score 16):

Another example from a real-life document I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ground}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, baseline=-3mm, thick]
    \draw (0,0) -- +(0mm,-4.0mm) {
        [yshift=-4mm]
        +(-2mm,0mm) -- +(2mm,0mm)
                +(-1mm,-1mm) -- +(1mm,-1mm)
                +(-0.3mm,-2mm) -- +(0.3mm,-2mm)
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

We have a text here, and then I refer to the ground (\ground) connection point in the instrument. Clearly, the \ground{} symbol will change the spacing... 
you can play with the \texttt{scale} and \texttt{baseline=-3mm} parameters in the definition\dots 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the snippet above]

Comment: Nicely done @Rmano.

Comment: +1 for the `baseline` option.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a suggestion on how to place inline and the tikz code not be high enough from the text.

```
\raisebox{-2pt}{\tikz{\draw[line width=1pt, >->] (0, 0) arc (-180:0:8pt);}}
```

The output that gave me was the following, which is quite good I guess.

[image]