# How to put a button image in text?

Tags: graphics

I want to put an image in latex in this way as you can see: by selecting the {image} Add SpatialLite Layer...option fro

[image] {imagen}

Comment: Welcome! What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `\includegraphics` of package `graphicx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Heiko suggested you can use `\includegraphics` Command of the `graphicx` package if the image already exists.

Here is a MWE (minimal working example):

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
 \usepackage{mwe} % Just needed here for the dummy image.
 \begin{document}
 by selecting the 
 \includegraphics[height=0.6\baselineskip]{example-image-a} 
 Add SpatialLite Layer\ldots{} option fro 
 \end{document}
```

If you want to create the picture inline on the fly, you may want to look at TikZ and the `\tikz{}` command as discussed here: [TikZ picture inline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313927/tikz-picture-inline).

Comment: BTW, the image `example-image-a`is part of the distribution package `mwe`, but it can be independently used and the loading of package `mwe` is not necessary.