# How to plot a bar chart within the text?

Tags: graphics

[image: bar chart inline with text]

I want to duplicate the bar chart in this paragraph. How can I do that using Latex? Is it even possible? I have used search keywords such as bar chart inline with the text, bar chart within the text, but I couldn't find what I am looking for. Any idea of how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some fluency with Tkiz, you could include it in the text as mentioned at [Tikz picture inline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313927/tikz-picture-inline).

Answer (score 6):

It's just an image.  Generate it as you would any other figure, paying attention to the scale and font sizes, then incorporate it with `\includegraphics`, *not* using a `figure` environment.

[image: inline bar chart]

To generate this I:

- made the graph in LibreOffice
- saved as a PDF
- opened it in Inkscape
- stripped it down the the essentials
- resized to 12pt high, keeping the aspect ratio (should have been 10pt)
- added the numbers
- cropped to exactly the objects required
- saved as graph.pdf
- included with the following code

inline.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
This is some text, surrounding a little inline bar chart (\includegraphics{/tmp/graph.pdf}).  The text carries on as if nothing had happened
\end{document}
```

Because I scaled it (almost) correctly in inkscape, I didn't need to use a size parameter in the call to `\includegraphics`

Comment: I didn't think we could use includegraphics, though it's very lengthy