# Drawing a rectangle above an inline tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

TikZ noob here: The following is a simplified and equivalentdescription of my problem.

The following TikZ code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[inner sep=0pt] (stony1) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=.04\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces the following a picture **inline** with my latex text [as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313932/17858) . However, I would like to add some tikz code that produces a blue rectangle above that same included image of the same (horizontal) width.  I should be able to customize the height of that rectangle.

What code should I add for this?

In a nutshell, I want to go from the following picture to

[image]

the following picture

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can draw a rectangle on top of the node containing the image.
The `yshift=1ex` adjusts the height of the blue box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (stony1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.04\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \fill[blue] (stony1.north west) rectangle ([yshift=1ex]stony1.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]