# DNA strand displacement: How to draw many harpoons over a harpoon so that their labels align?

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows

I would like to draw picture like this:

[image]

(This picture is snipped from a figure in [this research paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4150546/))

It is important that `a` and `a*` or `tb` and `tb*` or `tr` and `tr*` etc are vertically aligned (because they represent complementary strands of DNA and they should be vertically aligned in the figure for it to be meaningful.)

I tried something, like this:

```
$_{\xleftharpoondown[ta^*a^*tb^*b^*tr^*r^*tq^*]{}}^{\text{      }\xrightharpoonup{a\text{ }tb}\xrightharpoonup{b\text{ }tr}\xrightharpoonup{r\text{ }tq}}$
```

And it gives:

[image]

So few complaints about the above figure:

1. There is too much gap between the left harpoons and the right harpoons. How to fix this?
2. The most important thing - the labels `a` and `a*` etc HAVE to be aligned! How to do that?

Also BONUS (but not strictly necessary):

I would like to use such a figure inline (like an equation). Right now what I have can be used inline. I am not sure if a `tikz` figure can be used inline. So please demonstrate how to use this figure inline.

EDIT: This [stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313927/tikz-picture-inline) shows how to insert `tikz` figure inline. So the bonus question is kind of taken care of, if `tikz` is used. Please someone help me draw this with `tikz`!

EDIT:
How to add a gap in the middle? Like this:

[image]

Labels not shown in above image, but they will be there and have to be aligned. Using the solution in the answer I could create this:

[image]

In this the first arrow on the top is wrong. It should start under `ta` and end under `a`, so that a gap is exposed over `tb*`

EDIT: I could solve it! Here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[DNA=odd]
ta\ar[below] & a  & \,   & b \ar[below] & tr   & r \ar[below] & tq                      \\
ta^* & a^*          & tb^* & b^*          & tr^* & r^*          & tq^* \ar[llllll, above]
\end{tikzcd}
```

And this results in:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: It's best if you post your solution using the "Your Answer" box below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with something.

We're using a TikZ `\matrix` via TikZ-CD. The `DNA` style sets up some values that help us align things.

The `text depth` and `text height` key make sure that all nodes have the same height and depth which helps align the arrows below or above them.

Speaking of arrows, there are the keys `below` and `above` (not to be confused with `/tikz/above` and `/tikz/below`) that draw the harpoons above a number of nodes from right to left or below a number of nodes from left to right.

The `below` key uses `r` by default which means that without any settings further it will always underline the current and the next node to the `r`ight.

The `llllll` in the `above` arrow means that the arrow will end above the node six columns to the left.

The way, the `above` and `below` key are set up the `below` style should always be used from the end of a row and the left target should be specified.
The `above` key is best used in the first cell of a row.

---

Add [`baseline = -axis_height`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678935) to the `DNA` key to have the picture align how a matrix in math mode usually would.

---

It looks like pairs of nodes on the top line should be closer together, for a regular top row the `DNA*` style can be used with the argument `even` or `odd` which specifies where no `column sep` should be added.

For more irregular diagrams, you can use the `no csep` key that accepts a list of columns after which the `column sep` should be 0.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{
  no csep/.style={/utils/temp/.style={/tikz/column ##1/.append style={
    column sep=+0pt}},/utils/temp/.list={#1}},
  DNA/.style={
    column sep={\the\arraycolsep}, row sep=+.3em, thick,
    cells={inner xsep=+.15em, outer xsep=+.2em,
           text depth=+0pt, text height=+.7\ht\strutbox}},
  DNA*/.style={DNA, /tikz/every #1 column/.append style={column sep=+0pt}},
  above/.style={
    /tikz/arrows=-{Straight Barb[left]},
    to path={(\tikztostart.north east) -- (\tikztotarget.north west)}},
  below/.style={% implicitly one to the right
    r, /tikz/arrows=-{Straight Barb[left]},
    to path={(\tikztostart.south west) -- (\tikztotarget.south east)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[DNA*=even, cells={nodes={help lines,draw,text=black}}]
    & a \ar[below] & tb   & b \ar[below] & tr   & r \ar[below] & tq                      \\
  t & a^*          & tb^* & b^*          & tr^* & r^*          & tq^* \ar[llllll, above]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[DNA, no csep={1,4,6}]
  ta \ar[below] & a   & tb   & b \ar[below] & tr   & r \ar[below] & tq                      \\
  t             & a^* & tb^* & b^*          & tr^* & r^*          & tq^* \ar[llllll, above]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Excellent! This is a macro and can be reused conveniently!

Comment: But how would I add a gap in the middle? I think I don't understand how to use the `odd` and `even` correctly.

In the above there is a "gap" above the first `t`. Now I want to keep the bottom arrow as it is (t a* tb* b* tr* r* tq*). But on top I want t* a aligned with  t a* below. Then there is a gap above tb*. Then the two arrows b tr and r tq as before. How to do this?

Comment: I couldn't insert a figure in the comments. So I have added one in the main question under "EDIT".

Comment: Also the arrows on the top go "end-to-end". There is a gap between the arrow ahead and the tail of the next arrow. How to remove that gap or at least reduce that gap?

Comment: I could solve all the above! I my adding the solution in the main question as I can't add multi-line code here.

Comment: How does the keywords `odd` and `even` work? They are not defined in the macro. In the macros only `column sep={\the\arraycolsep}` is defined. So can you please explain what is going on? Are `odd` and `even` meaningful keywords coming from some other package?

Comment: @Inspired_Blue The `even` and `odd` values are used in the `/tikz/every #1 column` style defintion where it replaced `#1`. All it does is set the `column sep` between an `even`/`odd` numbered column and its next to zero. This pulls those pairs of column closer together. This only will make sense if the upper segments come in pairs. I will update my answer with another way to pull those pairs closer together (which isn't necessary if you don't need that at all).

Comment: That is interesting: how `odd` and `even` works! I have another problem: Sometimes the upper segments don't come in pairs. What can be done about it? For now I am using `\,` as an empty label if the arrow must cover only 1 label not 2 labels. Also `\ar[lll, below] doesn't seem to do anything. Like I would want to draw a long arrow below 3 labels. How to do that? Only `\ar[llll, above] worked for me. Am I using it wrong? p.s.: I modified `column sep={\the\arraycolsep}` to `column sep={0.5*\the\arraycolsep}` etc to pull those pairs closer. I would love to see if you have a better solution!